# Importing epub as a node

Tags: 7

Is there a module that imports epub book as a node into drupal? Or a way to do something like this by converting epub into something else before?

Comment: Drupal works on txt / HTML data. And have mechanisms to import XML and CSV data. If you know a way to convert ePub into one of them, tell us and we can guide you from that point. In theory you could store epub's content in DB and provide epub entity with proper rendering, but it would be a big, big task.

Comment: @Mołot ePub is XML isn't it? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB#Open_Packaging_Format_2.0.1#File_format

Comment: @Clive "EPUB internally uses XHTML or DTBook " - so not *is* but *uses*, and even that not always. My friend from e-publishing industry assured me epub 2 is now really a standard as most devices on market are not yet epub 3 ready.

Comment: @Mołot Oh right, the wrappers (OPF etc) are, but the things themselves aren't. I get ya

Answer (score 1):

It's in dev but the [Epub module](https://drupal.org/project/epub) is probably your best starting-point.

> The new epub module for Drupal 7 provides displays for file entity and file fields and enables users to read epub/ibooks files inside their browsers like pdf module.

It doesn't import as a node, but you can take a lot of code from that module to build your own node-import version.

Interestingly, the reverse operation has already been implemented in [Epub export](https://drupal.org/project/epub_export), so you might want to have a look at the code for that one too.

Comment: I guess it's always easier to export. In export, you must only know and understand parts you are going to use. In import you need to understand everything you may find. So to export you only need epub 2, for example, and even of that only a subset, and to import you need full options of epubs from 1 to 3 (and all media that can be embedded inside).